# Opengl rotate an object using the mouse (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, mouse, glut

I have an object that I want to rotate using the mouse in Opengl (I'm using glut). I'm keeping track of the mouse movement and rotate according to the change in x and y of the mouse. But the problem is that the object doesn't move how I want it to. For instance, when I move in x and then move in y and then move in x again, the object seems to move diagonally, while I want it to move from left to right. I know that this is because the newer rotations get done before the older rotations (resulting in unintuitive rotation) because of how matrix multiplication works.

But I have no idea of how to tackle this issue. One way I thought of is to change the axes about which I rotate according to the current rotation, but I have no idea if this will yield the correct result. Another thing I thought of is to make sure the latest rotation gets done last (but before glulookat translates the scene), but I don't know how to do this. 
So what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: We have no idea what the behavior of your code is and what behavior you would consider correct. You'll need to add your code and tell us exactly what it is doing and what you want it to do.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you want, but it seems like you're after an 'arcball' implementation of some type. Ken Shoemake's original paper is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.457.6530&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but you should be able to find implementations and descriptions of [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) online. Also, you want a quaternion describing the current state of rotation, and while animating, a temporary quaternion multiplied with the current until you 'release' the mouse, to prevent hysteresis.

Comment: Sorry if it is not 100 % clear what I mean. I googled  'arcball' and it is somehow what I want but less strict I guess. I just want to rotate based on the mouse movement, it is irrelevant if wether or not I am actually clicking the object. If I press the mouse button and I move from say, left to right, I want the object to rotate around it's y axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main approaches you can take.

- Use quaternions by projecting mouse coordinates onto a sphere (the arcball approach). Make the sphere the size of the window, so you don't have to worry about clicking an object.
- Rotate about y for horizontal mouse movement. Then, for vertical mouse movement, rotate around the cross product of the view vector and y (be careful if the cross product is zero). This is the approach used by Maya and others for orienting an editing view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I was already using your second method though. But since I'm looking straight down the -z axis  the cross product is the x axis (which I was rotating around). The problem I have is when I rotate it and it is multiplied with the current matrix it is applied before the rotation before that (if that makes sense). So it can happen that when I want to rotate left by moving my mouse to the left, the object is moving diagonally instead.